# Table rows are not rendering on separate lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to render a table, wherein each row of data is on a separate line. From my understanding, this is the default behavior for how data between `<tr></tr>` tags is rendered. At least, that is how it is has always functioned for me.

This is the code I am using:

```
function GetLastTen(){
    $.ajax({url: LastTen, success: function(result) {
        var location = document.getElementById('l_ten');
        location.innerHTML = "<table>\n";
        function format(location,object){
            location.innerHTML += '<tr>\n' +
                                     '<td>' + object.id + '</a></td>\n' +
                                  '</tr>\n';
        }
        $.each(result, function(elem){
            format(location, result[elem]);
        });
        location.innerHTML += "</table>"
    }});
}
```

The code obtains the proper data--there is nothing wrong with what I am getting from the API endpoint, but all the rows are on the same line.

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Try logging your result, my guess is that you're receiving the result as a text string, not as JSON, so you need to parse the result before iterating over it.

Comment: The data renders fine, originally there were more `<td>` elements. The API endpoint I am using already renders the data as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing a HTML string first into variable and setting the innerHTML once you are done:

```js
var result = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]

$(document).ready(function(){
  var location = $("#l_ten")
  var tableHTML = "<table>\n"

  function format(object){
      tableHTML += '<tr>\n<td>' + object.id + '</a></td>\n</tr>\n';
  }
  $.each(result, function(elem){
      format(result[elem]);
  });
  location.html(tableHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="l_ten"></div>
```